# Excel, split one cell into other specific cells based on the value from the first cell

Tags: excel, vba, replace, split, row

I wan't to split a cell with data, into other cells, based on the first data in the original cell. The data from the original cell looks like this (all in the same cell):

```
Field95-4,Field97-4,Field98-0,Field100-2,Field103-0,Field105-3,Field107-4,Field109-4,Field110-2,Field111-0,Field112-0,Field113-192,Field114-87,Field115-0,Field116-0,Field117-60
```

It should be split by "," and I found out that I could do that with a script:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim X As Variant
X = Split(Range("A1").Value, ",")
Range("A1").Resize(UBound(X) - LBound(X) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(X)
End Sub
```

Then the result is like this:

```
Field95-4
Field97-4
Field98-0
Field100-2
Field103-0
Field105-3
Field107-4
Field109-4
Field110-2
Field111-0
Field112-0
Field113-192
Field114-87
Field115-0
Field116-0
Field117-60
```

Now it should look for a cell containing the fieldnumber:

There is a cell containing the text: Field95, and a field with Field97 etc. Then I want to replace the text with the result: Field95 should be replaced by 4, and Field97 should be replaced with 4. etc.[image: This is the excel]

This should be the endresult

[image: End result]

I know it's much to ask, but I'we tried a lot, and I can't get it to work.

I'm looking forward to your answers. Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

This is an excel file I uploaded, so you can see what my question is about.
[link](http://www.misb.dk/questionWithData.xlsx)

UPDATE 2:

Maybe this, combined with an IF statement could be used?

```
Sub UpdateWhole()
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
.Replace "A1", "System", xlWhole
.Replace "A2", "System", xlWhole
.Replace "A3", "System", xlWhole
.Replace "B1", "ACC", xlWhole
.Replace "B2", "ACC", xlWhole
End With
End Sub
```

I don't know if that's an option?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
Sub RedHawk()
    Dim X As Variant
    X = Split(Range("A1").Value, ",")
    Range("A1").Resize(UBound(X) - LBound(X) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(X)
    For i = LBound(X) + 1 To UBound(X) + 1
        Cells(i, 1).Value = Split(Cells(i, 1).Value, "-")(1)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: It kinda works. The thing is, that it should "search" the sheet for the cell containing Field95, and then replace it with the value 4. The cell containing Field95 could be placed in any row in a Column. Do you get me? I think we are really close !

Comment: [link](http://www.misb.dk/questionWithData.xlsx) <-This is an excel file with an example of what I am asking for.

Comment: Hi Gary, Do you have any suggestion to the searching the sheet ?